# How to get the form element of the cursor in different forums or blogs to execute submit()?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use JavaScript to get the form element of the cursor in different forums or blogs to execute submit(), then submit the Input or Textarea that type is "submit", without clicking the submit button or pressing Enter or Ctrl+Enter.

I can not get the form element of the cursor in the input or textarea.

I try this, it only works in some forums to execute Search in the top but to Reply where the cursor is, and I can not set the different form numbers in every forum or blogs. It does not work in the Textarea that when press Ctrl+Enter can not submit.
`document.forms[0].submit()`

I try these, they still do not work anymore.
`this.submit()`
`this.form.submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done.

```
function getParentFormByChild(ele){
    while(ele.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body' && ele.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'form'){
        ele = ele.parentNode
    }
    if(ele.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body' ) return null
    return ele.parentNode
}

function 油猴子点击图标事件(){
    let ele = "油猴子获取当前光标所在input的dom元素"
    let fromEle = getParentFormByChild(ele)
    if(fromEle) fromEle.submit()
}
```